# Haproxy subdirectory backend to root path rewrite

Tags: haproxy

I have a haproxy with subdirectory app at backend.
For now I'm using `redirect location` from root path to subfolder.

But I want to replace/rewrite site url without subfolder.

For example:

```
Frontend: service.site.com
Backend: 1.2.3.4:8080/app1
```

I want to my back end looks like **service.site.com** without *app1* **service.site.com/app1** at end of URL

how can I do it with reqrep?

Haproxy 1.8

Answer (score 0):

you could do

`reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ (.*) \1\ /app1\2`

I added this on the backend, just before the server line

the first part is the method (GET / POST / ....) then the last part you do (.*) which means any url.

The target would be \1<space> (the method regex result, preserve the space in the request)

/app1 (your wished destination)

\2 would be everything that was in the url request, appended to your path